# Reducing Dimension For SVM in Sensor Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, dimensionality-reduction

I am looking for some suggestions on a problem that I am currently facing.

I have a set of sensor say S1-S100 which is triggered when some event E1-E20 is performed. Assume, normally E1  triggers S1-S20, E2 triggers S15-S30, E3 triggers S20-s50 etc and E1-E20 are completely independent events. Occasionally an event E might trigger any other unrelated sensor.

I am using  ensemble of 20 svm to analyze each event separately. My features are sensor frequency F1-F100, number of times each sensor is triggered and few other related features.

I am looking for a technique that can reduce the dimensionality of the sensor feature(F1-F100)/ or some techniques that encompasses all of the sensor and reduces the dimension too(i was looking for some information theory concept for last few days) . I dont think averaging, maximization is a good idea as I risk loosing information(it did not give me good result).

Can somebody please suggest what am I missing here? A paper or some starting idea...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might like to start with [Linear Discriminant Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis), it's a fairly simple algorithm and does more or less what you are looking for: dimensionality reduction and/or classification. It assumes each class is Gaussian distributed with different means but the same covariance. It's probably a good idea to plot some of the data beforehand to make sure that this assumption is reasonable. I've used the LDA implementation in R before. This was with about a dozen features, however. I'm not sure how it would scale to 100 dimensions.

It might also help to know why you want to reduce the dimension of the data. SVMs are commonly used with hundreds of thousands of (sparse) features, so what is the difficulty you have?

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i will try LDA.. i want to reduce dimension because in most of the cases if E1 triggers S1-S15, the value for rest of the sensor frequency F16-F100 will be zero, occasionally other sensor say S45, S50 can also be triggered few times...mainly I want to exclude all those zeros from the feature vector

Comment: Word of warning, LDA is also Latent Dirichlet Allocation, a related but very different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great article related to your question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction

Also, as @StompChicken mentions you shouldn't have any trouble making an SVM work with a few hundred features. You should start seeing (operational) issues at tens of thousands of features.

Carlos